# Make sphinx's autodoc show default values in parameters' description

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have the following docstring:

```
def progress_bar(progress, length=20):
    '''
    Returns a textual progress bar.

    >>> progress_bar(0.6)
    '[##########--------]'

    :param progress: Number between 0 and 1 describes the progress.
    :type progress: float
    :param length: The length of the progress bar in chars. Default is 20.
    :type length: int
    :rtype: string
    '''
```

Is there a way to tell `sphinx` to add the "Default is X" part to the parameters' description if available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defaults to` is the keyword now. See https://github.com/sglvladi/Sphinx-RTD-Tutorial/blob/a69fd09/docs/source/docstrings.rst#the-sphinx-docstring-format

```
"""[Summary]

:param [ParamName]: [ParamDescription], defaults to [DefaultParamVal]
:type [ParamName]: [ParamType](, optional)
...
:raises [ErrorType]: [ErrorDescription]
...
:return: [ReturnDescription]
:rtype: [ReturnType]
"""
```

Answer (score 5):

I have adopted Voy's answer and made a [package](https://github.com/zwang123/sphinx-autodoc-defaultargs) which automatically does this for you. You are very welcome to try it and to report issues.

The following code

```py
def func(x=None, y=None):
    """
    Example docstring.

    :param x: The default value ``None`` will be added here.
    :param y: The text of default value is unchanged.
              (Default: ``'Default Value'``)
    """

    if y is None:
        y = 'Default Value'
    pass
```

will be rendered like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhe3c.png) if the default theme is used, and like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxl4Q.png) with `sphinx_rtd_theme`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible and must be done manually.

Comment: This is very possible.

Comment: @W4t3randWind would be nice if you posted an answer that actually tells is how then

Comment: It was just a snide comment that the authors excluded this feature. It's *possible* it's just not a feature Sphinx supports.

Answer (score 1):

While it is still manual, this is one method I use to stylize the default argument values more distinctly:

---

[image: example of this method]

---

Added a [ReST substitution](https://sublime-and-sphinx-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reuse.html): [(Where to put it?)](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions)

```
.. |default| raw:: html

    <div class="default-value-section"> <span class="default-value-label">Default:</span>
```

Then used it in docstring:

```py
"""
:type host: str
:param host: Address of MongoDB host. |default| :code:`None`

:type port: int
:param port: Port of the MongoDB host. |default| :code:`None`
"""
```

and a little styling through [custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980230/3508719):

*(note that you may need to add some extra rules to this CSS to override the styling of your theme, for instance: `html.writer-html5 .rst-content ul.simple li` worked for me)*

```css
.default-value-section {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.default-value-section .default-value-label {
    font-style: italic;
}
.default-value-section code {
    color: #666;
}
```

*Note that **I haven't tested** this method with multiple [Sphinx themes](https://sphinx-themes.org/) and it may need adjustments for other themes. Tested with `sphinx_rtd_theme` theme. Also note that this relies on HTML closing that first `<div>` automatically which is a bit naughty. Would be sick for ReST to support default parameter values natively.*