# How to add custom CSS file to Sphinx?

Tags: python, css, python-sphinx

How can I add a custom CSS file? The following `conf.py` does not work:

```py
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_theme = 'default'
html_theme_options = {
  'cssfiles': ['_static/style.css']
}
```

Result:

```
$ make html
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 50%] help
reading sources... [100%] index

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents...
Theme error:
unsupported theme option 'cssfiles' given
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079200/how-do-i-set-up-custom-styles-for-restructuredtext-sphinx-readthedocs-etc/68394150#68394150

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A simpler way is to add this to your `conf.py`:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('css/custom.css')  # may also be an URL
```

Then put the file into the `_static/css/` folder.

Comment: add javascript files via `app.add_javascript('file.js')`.

Comment: After doing that, I still have to manually add a reference to the css in the html file... Anything more automatic?

Comment: @Tony been a while, but may be a function of the theme.

Comment: perhaps worthwhile to note that [alabaster theme](https://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) works out-of-the box with a `_static/custom.css` file in source folder so `add_styleshee('custom.css')` would not be needed for this theme.

Comment: This works with this line: html_static_path = ['_static']

Answer (score 25):

You should be able to include custom css by extending the default sphinx theme. In your conf.py you would specify where your extension to the theme would be, such as.

```
# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']
```

Then in _templates you would create a extension to the default theme named 'layout.html' that would include your cssfiles such as.

```
{# layout.html #}
{# Import the layout of the theme. #}
{% extends "!layout.html" %}

{% set css_files = css_files + ['_static/style.css'] %}
```

See sphinx's documentation on [templating](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html) for more information.

Comment: Could you explain, what is symbol `!` means?

Comment: "By prefixing the name of the overridden template with an exclamation mark, Sphinx will load the layout template from the underlying HTML theme." I've added a link to the sphinx documentation on templating above. Mainly that line is called to extend the default sphinx layout.html, or whatever theme you might have installed.

Comment: Thx, one more question plz: You example work as expected after `make html`, but does not work on [readthedocs.org](http://readthedocs.org) with default theme(sphinx_rtd_theme).

Comment: You are correct. I just pulled the sphinx_rtd_theme down and tried to extend the theme with my custom css, and the sphinx_rtd_theme overrides that css. I searched the github issues and this seems to be a problem with other css as well. [github issue 117](https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/117). I'll continue to play with it and see, if I can get it to work with the theme, but it seems to be a current limitation of sphinx_rtd_theme as mentioned in that issue.

Comment: Thx for the link, `add_stylesheet` solved my problem.

Comment: I noticed that the css will not be rebuilt when I use sphinx-autobuild.

Comment: FTR the templating link is now https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html. SO wouldn't let me suggest an edit to the answer for some reason so I'm pointing it here.

Answer (score 16):

The options that you can configure via `html_theme_options` are theme-dependent.  Check out the `[options]` section of your theme’s `theme.conf` to find out what is available.

On a global basis, though, you can define `html_context` in your `conf.py` to override the settings for `css_files` (and, for that matter, `script_files` too):

```
html_context = {
    'css_files': ['_static/custom.css'],
}
```

(For reference, have a look at Sphinx’s `builders.html.StandaloneHTMLBuilder.prepare_writing()` and see [how `self.globalcontext` gets populated there](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/b12b39db05d605cfb946f84afd27e0f6cf3c9e13/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L491).)

Comment: Thank you!  Out of the answers provided, this is what helped me override annoying auto-hyphenation in the basic.css.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Sphinx 3.2.

I was able to add some simple custom CSS by doing the following:

- add this line in `conf.py` right under `html_static_path = ['_static']`:

```
html_css_files = ['css/custom.css']
```

- go to `docs/_static/` and add `css/custom.css`
- add custom css to your file then `$ make html`

[Source](https://blog.readthedocs.com/custom-css-and-js-in-sphinx/)

Comment: This is the approach recommended by [ReadTheDocs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) and [Furo](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/customisation/injecting/#injecting-code)