# Modifying sphinx_bootstrap_theme method rendering

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

I have some [API Documentation](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_CiscoConfParse.html) which I'm mostly happy with.

I'm using the `sphinx_bootstrap_theme` to render my doc style.  However, I want to modify how each API method renders.

Today the docs look like this:
[image: ccp_jumbled]

I want to make a small change to the bootstrap theme, such that I get an HR between every method like this:
[image: ccp_segmented]

**QUESTION:**
Where do I modify `sphinx_bootstrap_theme` such that I can customize the rendering of these methods?

I looked through the [`sphinx_bootstrap_theme` templates](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/tree/master/sphinx_bootstrap_theme/bootstrap), but I can't seem to find the template I have to monkey with to make this work right.

If you want to see how I've configured my docs, you can find the source tree [here](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/tree/master/sphinx-doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is a bit tricky to tweak the original code. What I personally do and so far was happy with is the overwrite the existing style by [adding a custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462494/how-to-add-custom-css-file-to-sphinx) to implement some minor changes. The way I do it:

- Create a folder called `css` under `source/_static`
- Add a new css (for example: `custom.css`) file that includes your desired changes.
- Add the following code to your `conf.py`

```py
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('css/custom.css')
```

- Save and build

For more check [this](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html)

Comment: I see, my bad. I assumed it is similar to [basicstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxjp.themes.basicstrap/)

Comment: doh, it was my bad... I should have heeded the path you put in your example... it worked after tweaking it... I just added 1em padding and it renders much more cleanly now

Comment: Glad it helped.