# How can make math equation left-aligned instead of center-aligned in reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The below text can create a simple math equation in reStructuredText:

```
.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } }
```

By default it is center-aligned when `make html` make the text as html ,i want to make the format:

1. make it left-aligned
2. left-aligned and add 4 blank whites at the line's beginning

I almost solve it with a simple way that ebeding a  `math` in `raw html`:

```
vim   "source/ebed equation in div.rst"
ebed equation in raw html
==================================
normal equation

.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } } 

equation ebeded in div

.. raw:: html

   <div style="margin-left:20px;width:300px;height:120px;">
.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } }
```

The style `width:300px;height:450px;` is more smaller than before,it make  equation left-aligned even the equation is still center-aligned in div.
The style `margin-left:20px;` add a blank white at the beginning.
Compile it with `make html`,open it in browser:

[image]

There is a little bug,the element div is not closed!
If i close the div tag this way:

```
vim   "source/ebed equation in div.rst"
ebed equation in raw html
==================================
normal equation

.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } } 

equation ebeded in div

.. raw:: html

   <div style="margin-left:20px;width:300px;height:120px;">
.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } } 

   </div>
```

It will be shown as below after compiling it:

[image]

The html tag `</div>` will be shown as a new line of equation.
How can close the div tag scrupulously with logically right way?

Comment: `make html` make it as a html file.

Comment: Do you use MathJax? Do you want all equations to be left-aligned, or just one?

Comment: Make it simple ,make it stupid,just `.. math::`,make equation ebeded in `math` left-aligned.

Comment: Without  MathJax,just specified equation ebeded in `.. math::`.

Comment: Why don't you use [custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462494/how-to-add-custom-css-file-to-sphinx)?

Answer (score 0):

The first `.. raw:: html` means start of html,the second `.. raw:: html` which contains `</div>` means stop of html,something alike php.

```
.. raw:: html

   <div style="margin-left:20px;width:300px;height:120px;">
.. math::

   \frac{1}{\Bigl(\sqrt{\phi \sqrt{5}}-\phi\Bigr) e^{\frac25 \pi}} =
   1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}} {1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}
   {1+\frac{e^{-8\pi}} {1+\ldots} } } } 

.. raw:: html

   </div>
```