# Left-align all math blocks in Sphinx HTML output

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax, restructuredtext

I have Sphinx documentation containing math blocks via [the `math` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-math). By default, they are centered in the HTML output. I want them all to appear aligned at the left, but with some indentation with respect to the surrounding text.

For example, if this is in `index.rst`

```
For :math:`|r| < 1`:

.. math::

   \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}

Text in following paragraph put here to demonstrate that the math block
is in fact centered on the page.
```

and `conf.py` is completely empty, then running `sphinx-build . output` in the same folder produces the following HTML page as viewed in the browser:

[image: rendered HTML]

I want that formula and all other math blocks left-aligned with something like 2 ["em"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4239) indentation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70323404) asks how to left-align a single math block. I'm hoping there is a way to achieve the same effect throughout the documentation without changing each and every math directive in the reStructuredText source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer applies to MathJax, the default mathematics renderer in HTML output.

The following setting in conf.py left-aligns all `math` directive content:

```
mathjax3_config = {'chtml': {'displayAlign': 'left'}}
```

Indentation can be customized with `displayIndent`:

```
mathjax3_config = {'chtml': {'displayAlign': 'left',
                             'displayIndent': '2em'}}
```

References:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#confval-mathjax3_config
- https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v3.0-latest/options/output/index.html#options-common-to-all-output-processors